# Error - enabling bin log in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, my.cnf, binlog, mysqlbinlog

I have a mysql server with 5.5. I tried to enable the binlog using the below config file.

```
# BINARY LOGGING #
server_id                      = 1
log_bin                        = /mysql/binlog/mysql_bin
expire_logs_days               = 14
sync_binlog                    = 1
max_binlog_size                = 100M
```

/mysql/binlog/ is owned by mysql:mysql

After restart mysql I got the below error.

```
mysqld: File '/mysql/binlog/mysql-bin.index' not found (Errcode: 13)
```

So I tried this command.

added this to my.cnf

```
binlog_do_db                   = mydb    
log_bin_index                  = /mysql/binlog/mysql-bin.index
```

And executed this commands.

```
touch /mysql/binlog/mysql-bin.index
chown mysql:mysql /mysql/binlog/mysql-bin.index
```

But still its throwing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Please never mind, I found a solution on this blog.

Still the mysql data directory points to `/var/lib/mysql`

https://schworak.com/blog/e53/move-mysql-binlog-to-another-disk-or-folder/

Then did chmod 700 binlog.